# ESXi 4.0 with one public IP

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esxi

Hello I've been trying to get this server working but so far no luck.  I have an ESXi v4 server collocate where I'm being supplied one public IP.  By default the management interface is attached to the physical NIC so right now I'm able to connect to server using vSphere client.  I tried using one of the VMs as a router (m0n0wall) using 2 interfaces one internal and the other external (where I would attach the physical NIC), then port forward the ports for vSphere to the management interface which I have on same internal vSwitch as the m0n0wall internal interface.  When I do that I can no longer connect to using vSphere.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What device is that actually presents your single public IP? if it's a router then you can either move the ESXi's management ports from 80/443/902/903 to something else or advertise your own service to a non port 80/443/902/903 block and let the router just NAT them. If it's your actual ESXi box that's running the IP then you're out of luck, its management interface will own the IP and won't allow guest traffic over it - although it will happily share a single NIC - that's how the router/NAT method works. You could always buy more public IPs of course.

Comment: Right now I'm getting the public IP from a router which I don't have access to. How can I change the management ports from 80/443/902/903 to something else?

Comment: 'from the router' as in via DHCP? this is probably best discussed with your provider to be honest as there's lots of ways to do this and most if not all will require their help and involvement.

Comment: I have a static IP address which is public. Right now I have management interface with that IP address so I can log in to vSphere.  Eventually I want to have some sort of VM router that acts as the gateway for all VMs including the management network.  There are no firewalls in front of my server, basically my server is wide open to the internet.